# Python Thread cancel 3rd Party running function

Tags: python, multithreading

I am calling a 3rd party function that I have not written so I cannot edit it.
It has its own logic that may take some time to finish.

I wrapped that 3rd party call into a thread and I wanted to immediately cancel it once I received some event.

```
import threading
import time

# Assume this is the 3rd party function
def call_3rd_party_function():
    for i in range(50):
        print("Executing task " + str(i))
        time.sleep(0.25)


def task(stop_event: threading.Event):
    print("Starting background thread!")
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        call_3rd_party_function()


stop_event = threading.Event()
t = threading.Thread(target=task, args=(stop_event,))
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()

time.sleep(5)
stop_event.set()
t.join()

print("Main thread end!")
```

In the code above, example after 5 seconds.. I want to cancel that task, but my output is not what I want as the 3rd party function still continue with its tasks to completion.

```
Starting background thread!
Executing task 0
Executing task 1
Executing task 2
Executing task 3
.
.
Executing task 49
Main thread end!
```

Is there a way to do this?  I wrapped it in a thread since I want it to run on its own so as not to block the main thread from doing some other things.

Any hints?

Comment: Run it as a `Process` rather than as a `Thread` and then call `terminate()` on the instance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, so this is something that cannot be solved by any Python Multithreading tools?  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I know of no way of terminating a thread without its cooperation.